# Splitting a computer's display similar to multiple monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-server-2008-r2

so I work through a remote desktop and there's very long wait times since I render some videos and basically don't have to move a thing for a variably long time, I'd like to be able to be in fullscreen in half 1 and in remote desktop in half 2 of the display as to keep a watchful eye on it all the time, do you know of a way to achieve this? I currently use SplitView but it's nothing more than resizing windows, it doesn't support fullscreen in either of the halves.

I'm sorry if this is not the correct board to ask this question, I don't know where to take this question to.

Comment: Interesting! I would imagine there's a way to do this, either by writing a custom display driver, or (if using Linux) by configuring `X.org` in a special way. However, buying a second monitor would definitely be cheaper than acquiring the knowledge!

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Which version?

Comment: it's a windows server 2008 R2